# Question about existence of a weak solution to a non-linear PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I am trying to show that $u$ is a weak solution to the following Navier-Stokes equations with partial dissipation
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\partial_tu+(u\cdot\nabla)u=-\nabla p+\nu\partial_{22} u, \\
\nabla\cdot u=0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
So I have a sequence $u^n$ satisfying the following two condition:

$u^n$ is uniformly bounded  in $X$ and it converges weakly to a limit $u$ in $X$,

$\partial_t u^n$ is uniformly bounded in $Y$ and  it also converges weakly to $\partial_t u$ in $Y$, where $X \subset Y$ are two complete spaces and $T>0$.

My question is: why do we need to extract another subsequence of the sequence $u^n$ that converges strongly to u in order to show that $u$ is a weak solution of the above system?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably to handle the bilinear term $(u\cdot\nabla)u$, since weak convergence on its own does not play nicely with objects like that one; though this is just a guess. It would help if you gave a little more info on the specifics of the problem.

Comment: Hi @Jose27, the sequence $u^n$ converges weakly to u in $L^{2}(0,T,B_{2,1}^{2})$ and                      $\partial_tu^{n}$ is bounded and converges weakly also to $\partial_t u$ in  $L^{2}(0,T,B_{2,1}^{2})$ where $B_{2,1}^{2}$ is the inhomogeneous Besov space.  I know that I need to use the Aubin-Lions Lemma in order to extract another subsequence that converges strongly to $u$ , but I am not sure why do we need to do that? Thanks

Comment: The statement of Aubin-Lions Lemma can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma